# Adding CCSprite on Tiled tile properties

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tile

I'm trying to add a Sprite beside the player, but only when the Tile beside the player is NOT a Wall. I know that the Tiled tiles are working properly, as they do their job in this method:

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(tileCoord.x, tileCoord.y - 1);
if ([self isValidTileCoord:p] && ![self isWallAtTileCoord:p]) {
    [tmp addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
    t = YES;
```

I am checking for Tiled on coordinate with these two methods:

```
-(BOOL)isProp:(NSString*)prop atTileCoord:(CGPoint)tileCoord forLayer:(CCTMXLayer *)layer {
if (![self isValidTileCoord:tileCoord]) return NO;
int gid = [layer tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
NSDictionary * properties = [_tileMap propertiesForGID:gid];
if (properties == nil) return NO;    
return [properties objectForKey:prop] != nil;
}



-(BOOL)isWallAtTileCoord:(CGPoint)tileCoord {
return [self isProp:@"Wall" atTileCoord:tileCoord forLayer:_bgLayer];
}
```

(Thanks RayWenderlich)

And my code for adding the sprite is

```
CGPoint tileCoord =  ccp(_player.position.x - 24 +60, player.position.y);
CGPoint cTileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:tileCoord];

NSLog(@" t: %@, c: %@",
    CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation(tileCoord),
    CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation(cTileCoord)
    );

if (![self isWallAtTileCoord:cTileCoord])
{
    NSLog(@"False");
    circle1.position = ccp(_player.position.x - 24 +60, _player.position.y);
    [self addChild:circle1];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"True");
}
```

What I want this to do is to only add the `Circle1` sprite to the left of the player when there isn't a `Wall` tile there. The problem is that this code always detects false, no matter if there is a wall there or not. Do any of you guys understand why it does not detect the walls properly and how I can fix it?

Comment: Well to ask the obvious, have you checked to see if your "wall" tiles are on the `_bgLayer` and that they have the exact property of `Wall` set to True?

Comment: And if they are I would NSLog the position where you are trying to add the sprite (not the tile coord position) and then NSLog the tile coord position that is being test in `isProp`.

Comment: @stenger96  It all logs the same.. http://pastebin.com/10AqetvC

Comment: Do you think you could post a link so I could download the project and test it myself?

Comment: Yeah, sure, here it is. @stenger96 . The logging is a bit crazy atm tho, you might want to remove some. Here, sorry for the long wait, Mediafire decided not to work on me... -.- https://mega.co.nz/#!VwMFXCgS!L5r5q0LdifoLluLybHrMxg8xr0AT_6iwcNA-r0yPt2o

Comment: Alright well I'm having some trouble getting it to run but what you could try is logging all the positions (tile coord) positions of your wall tiles.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that tomorrow. Right now I have to read up before my drivers license theory test, so I will be back tomorrow, sorry. And I will try to make a working download aswell, cant really see why that one isnt but yeah.

Comment: If you found your answer, Oscar, post it as an answer (if an existing answer doesn't cover the answer already).  Posting the 'answer' working code into your question just confuses the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I just named the layer in Tiled something else than I did in XCODE. No code issue, just me messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your tile map has the correct layer settings. I did a mistake with this once, it is easy to forget

Answer (score 2):

Last year me also observed same problem in retina mode. It worked in non retina but not detected in retina mode.

So finally used custom dictionary to check edge tile. Integer comparison takes less CPU time than string comparison. So replaced it with enum.

**Go for this approach only if none other simple way worked.**

I used this code to find edge of the tile that set in meta property.

```
typedef enum GRID_TYPE{
    kGrideType_Normal = 4001,
    kGrideType_Collidable,
    kGrideType_Collectable,      
    kGrideType_Sea,
    kGrideType_Edge,
    kGrideType_enemy,
    kGrideType_gold,

}GridType;
```

//Init tilemap and grid type

```
tileMap.meta = [tileMap layerNamed:PP_TILE_META_LAYER];
[tileMap initTileAnimation];
```

//Somewhere in code

```
CGPoint point = [self getTileCoordForPosition:position];

GridType type = [self getTileType:point];

if(type == kGrideType_Edge)
{
   //touched edge tile....
}
```

Functions:

```
-(GridType)getTileType:(CGPoint)pos 
{        
// not defined USE_COCOS2D_FOR_TILE_IDENTIFICATION

#ifdef USE_COCOS2D_FOR_TILE_IDENTIFICATION
    GridType type = kGrideType_Normal;

    CGPoint tileCoord = position;//[self tileCoordForPosition:position];
    unsigned int tileGid = [self.meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
    if (tileGid) {
        NSDictionary *properties = [self propertiesForGID:tileGid];        
        if (properties)
        {
            NSString *collision = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_COLLIDABLE];

            if (collision && [collision caseInsensitiveCompare:@"true"] == NSOrderedSame) 
            {
                type = kGrideType_Collidable ;
            }
            NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_COLLECTABLE];
            if (collectable && [collectable caseInsensitiveCompare:@"true"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                type = kGrideType_Coin ;
            }

            NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_CHEST];
            if (collectable && [collectable caseInsensitiveCompare:@"true"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                type = kGrideType_Chest ;
            }

        }
    }
    return type;    
#else
    int type = [[mTileInfoDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TILE(%d,%d)", (int)pos.x,(int)pos.y]] intValue];

    GridType gType = kGrideType_Normal;

    if(type!=0)
        gType = (GridType)type;

    return (GridType)gType;
#endif
}



-(void)initTileAnimation
{    
    mTileInfoDict   = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //Parse all the tile in map

    mBgLayer = [self layerNamed:PP_TILE_MAP_BG_LAYER];

    int rowSize = self.mapSize.width ; 
    int colSize = self.mapSize.height ; 

    for(int x=0; x<rowSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<colSize; y++) 
        {
            CGPoint tileCord = ccp(x,y) ;


            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TILE(%d,%d)", (int)tileCord.x,(int)tileCord.y];


            GridType tileType = kGrideType_Normal;

            unsigned int tileGid = [self.meta tileGIDAt:tileCord];


            if (tileGid) 
            {
                NSDictionary *properties = [self propertiesForGID:tileGid];

                if (properties)
                {        
                    /* Check Tile :  IS SEA - TILE */


                    NSString *sea = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_SEA];

                    if (sea && [sea isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
                    {
                        tileType = kGrideType_Sea;

                        [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tileType] forKey:key];

                        continue;
                    }

                    /* Check Tile :  IS Inky - TILE */



                    /* Check Tile :  IS COLLECTABLE - COIN */

                    NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_COLLECTABLE];

                    if (collectable && [collectable isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
                    {
                        tileType = kGrideType_Collectable;

                        [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tileType] forKey:key];

                        PPCoins *coinSprite = [PPCoins spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"coin_0000.png"];
                        coinSprite.tag = kTagCoinSprite;
                        coinSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);

                        CCSprite *sprite = [mBgLayer tileAt:tileCord];

                        coinSprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x+coinSprite.contentSize.width*0.5f, sprite.position.y+coinSprite.contentSize.height*0.5f) ;

                        [self addChild:coinSprite z:3 tag:kTagCoinSprite];
                        [coinSprite runAnimation];

                        {
                            coinSprite.key = key;
                            [mCoinDict setObject:coinSprite forKey:key];
                        }
                        continue;
                    }



                    /* Check Tile :  IS COLLIDABLE - TILE */

                    NSString *collidable = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_COLLIDABLE];

                    if (collidable && [collidable isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
                    {
                        tileType = kGrideType_Collidable;

                        [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tileType] forKey:key];

                        continue;
                    }

                    /* Check Tile :  IS Edge - TILE */

                    NSString *edge = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_EDGE];

                    if (edge && [edge isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
                    {
                        tileType = kGrideType_Edge;

                        [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tileType] forKey:key];

                        continue;
                    }


                    NSString *redTargetCoin = [properties valueForKey:TILE_PROPERTY_TARGET_COIN];

                    if (redTargetCoin && [redTargetCoin isEqualToString:@"true"]) 
                    {
                        tileType = kGrideType_TargetCoins;

                        [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tileType] forKey:key];
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    [mTileInfoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kGrideType_Normal] forKey:key];
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

    - (CGPoint)getTileCoordForPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
//    CGPoint nodeSpace1 = [self convertToNodeSpace:position];
//    float x = floor(nodeSpace1.x / self.tileSize.width);
//    float y = floor(self.mapSize.height - (nodeSpace1.y / self.tileSize.height));
//    
//    if( x >= TILE_IN_ROW)
//        x = TILE_IN_ROW - 1;
//    
//    if( y >= TILE_IN_COL)
//        y = TILE_IN_COL - 1;    
//
//    return ccp(x, y);

    int maxTileCol = self.mapSize.height;// (_tileMap.contentSize.height)/TILE_SIZE;

    int x = ( (position.x-self.position.x)/TILE_SIZE);
    int y = maxTileCol - ( ((position.y)-self.position.y)/TILE_SIZE);

    if( x >= TILE_IN_ROW)
        x = TILE_IN_ROW - 1;

    if( y >= TILE_IN_COL)
        y = TILE_IN_COL - 1;

    return ccp(x, y);

}
```